# New cooker needs wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

Hi I just bought a new cooker that says on the back it's 9.5kw to 10.7kw so was wondering what cable would be best 6mm or 10mm iv got a 35amp fuse in the breaker but do have a 50amp one I can put in. on a watt to amp calculator it said about 45 amp and in the manual it just said minimum 32amp cable.
Any help greatly appreciated
Thanks
Ben

Comment: Are you sure it takes 10.7 **kilo**watts? That's like 90 amps. You'd be talking some massive industrial oven to draw that much. And since you're talking wires in mm, I assume you're in the UK?

Comment: Hi.thanks for the reply and yes I'm from UK. It says on the back   230-240v     50hz      9800 - 10700w     the model is indesit ID60C2

Comment: Ok, after a bit of searching I found [this page](https://www.diy.com/departments/indesit-id60c2-w-s-electric-double-cooker-with-ceramic-hob/1113545_BQ.prd) which says it takes 32A. You're likely looking at the kilowatt *hours* rating, which is a measure of energy efficiency.

Comment: @Machavity -- 10.7kW is a fairly normal size for a full-sized cooker (range/stove)

Answer (score -1):

You say you've got a 35A fuse and the unit takes 32A. So, on that front, you're good.

I'm not sure how UK wire is sold size-wise, but what you'll want to do is find some 3.5-4mm copper wire, which is rated for at least 40A (in the US we call it 8 gauge). It might be ideal to find it in a cable (hot, neutral and ground) for ease of running.

Comment: thanks I have got some I'd say about a meter to a meter an half of 6mm 35amp cable an the socket to hard wire it in is literally behind the cooker. iv never wired a cooker before but am competent with stuff like that just wanted to be sure as don't want to damage my partners brand new oven, she won't be best pleased.

Comment: Either the unit will have its own box or you can wire a box behind it to join the unit's wires to your home wiring. Just make sure to match the wires up correctly.

Comment: iv got a circuit box with a 35amp breaker fuse already in labeled cooker from previous tenants, I'm assuming it's just a case now of brown to brown, blue to blue and earth to earth.